# spring / hibernate project do not import data into database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, import

In my current spring / hibernate project, I just added a file `import.sql` to my folder `WEB-INF`, but when deploy to server, no data is imported into the database, even the tables being created without problem.

my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.kleber" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource restDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql:mydata");
        dataSource.setUsername("kleber");
        dataSource.setPassword("123");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "/WEB-INF/import.sql");
                setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

my import.sql file:

```
INSERT INTO credencial (nome) VALUES ('categoria');
INSERT INTO credencial (nome) VALUES ('produto');
INSERT INTO credencial (nome) VALUES ('pagina');
INSERT INTO credencial (nome) VALUES ('usuario');
INSERT INTO credencial (nome) VALUES ('admin');

INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('insert_categoria');
INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('update_categoria');
INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('delete_categoria');

INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('insert_produto');
INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('update_produto');
INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('delete_produto');

INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('insert_pagina');
INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('update_pagina');
INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('delete_pagina');

INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('insert_usuario');
INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('update_usuario');
INSERT INTO autorizacao (nome) VALUES ('delete_usuario');

INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (1,3);

INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (2,4);
INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (2,5);
INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (2,6);

INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (3,7);
INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (3,8);
INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (3,9);

INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (4,10);
INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (4,11);
INSERT INTO credencial_autorizacao VALUES (4,12);

INSERT INTO usuario (login, senha, nome, sobrenome, email) VALUES ('klebermo', '202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70', 'kleber', 'mota', 'kleber@mail.com');

INSERT INTO usuario_credencial VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO usuario_credencial VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO usuario_credencial VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO usuario_credencial VALUES (1,4);
INSERT INTO usuario_credencial VALUES (1,5);
```

Anyone can tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `import.sql` should be in the root of your classpath, so put it inside `\WEB-INF\classes` and it will be picked up.

Comment: this could be done during the build process? like basically everything else which is placed in this directory?

Comment: Yes, place the `import.sql` inside your `src/main/resources` directory and it should be added to the classpath automatically (assuming a maven like project structure and build process).

Comment: putting the file in this directory, do I still need indicate it in the configuraton class (property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files`)? If so, I could use the path `/src/main/resources/import.sql`?

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify the filename since hibernate automatically will look for `import.sql` in the root of the classpath.  The only reason you'd need to specify it would be if you named it something else.  For sake of answering your question fully, if you had named it `mota.sql`, you'd need to specify it as a property with the value of `mota.sql` since Hibernate will look at the root of the classpath for you.